# Moon photography

Tags: lens, equipment-recommendation, moon, aps-c

Hi I am a photography hoobyist. At the moment I am using a Nikon D3100 with the standard kit lens (18-55mm). I am interested in taking photos of the moon. I am debating whether to buy a 55-200mm lens or a 55-300mm lens. Which one would be better?

P.S I am on a tight budget and I am looking for a lens for personal use, not commercial.

Would appreciate any answers!

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to come anywhere close to filling the frame when photographing the moon focal length is *everything*. Get the longest focal length lens you can afford. Unless you can afford a 1000mm+ lens, you will still need to crop your images for the moon to fill most of the frame.

Comment: I can only just fill the sensor on my 5dmkiii with a 2800mm telescope attached - so yes, 1000+ indeed :)